# AppleScript - How to send a email without the mail app opening up

Tags: email, applescript, send

I need to know how to send a email with applescript without having a email to send from. So basically using the mail app is out because I have to have the use input their email in order to send.

Could I do a shell script in side the applescript in order to send?

Answer (score 1):

Try my python email shell script [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/pythonEmail/pythonEmail.html). I have an example applescript at the bottom of the page showing how you can control the shell script from applescript.