# Send email from clipboard without opening mail.app

Tags: applescript, keyboard-maestro

I searched for how to send email without opening apple mail, and found the question [AppleScript - How to send a email without the mail app opening up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767884/applescript-how-to-send-a-email-without-the-mail-app-opening-up)

However, I'm doing this with Keyboard maestro, so that I can send a specific email using a hot key in any application. After googling for the solution I found this script that does the job well:

```
tell application "Mail"
set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"hello", content:"You got a new file in your Downloads folder, girl!", visible:true}
tell theNewMessage
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"myemail@mail.com"}
    send
end tell
```

end tell

One problem: I want to do this, but instead of *hello* in the subject, I want to have **the clipboard**. Googling for that, I found two things

```
keystroke "v" using {command down}
```

or

```
return (the clipboard)
```

I tried to teplace "Hello" with those two. But none of them work.

I don't know applescript, thus googling around and my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
set a to "myemail@mail.com"
tell application "Mail"
    tell (make new outgoing message)
        set subject to (the clipboard)
        set content to "content"
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:a}
        send
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Can you make a new script that makes it so that the Subject is the first 10 words, and *iff* the clipboard har more than 10 words, then the clipboard is cut off, for example like this "hello there baby this is a long message sent with... [see notes]" and then *the whole message* is in the content of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that happens to work for me very well. I'll just post it as an example.

```
tell application "System Events"
    activate application "Mail"
    set the clipboard to "Subject Line"
    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke tab
    set the clipboard to "This is the contents.\nLine 2 of the contents."
    keystroke "v" using command down
end tell
```

I use this script after clicking on an e-mail address in the browser. I choose the relevant Mail script from my AppleScript menu after making sure that the text insertion point is in the subject line of my e-mail.