# Send email from clipboard without opening Thunderbird

Tags: email, autohotkey

I asked a question called [Send email from clipboard without opening mail.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041535/send-email-from-clipboard-without-opening-mail-app)

Now, I can do this using

```
set a to "post+UPReuNmbK7pR+414760@checkvist.com"
tell application "Mail"
    tell (make new outgoing message)
        set subject to (the clipboard)
        set content to ""
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:a}
        send
    end tell
end tell
```

I want to do the same in windows 7, preferably using AHK and Mozilla Thunderbird, since I already have these programs installed. I cannot, however, write this due to my poor programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on lifehacker, here http://lifehacker.com/355941/quickly-compose-new-gmail-messages-with-launchy