# Send email from clipboard without opening mail.app -- with conditions

Tags: macos, applescript

I asked the question [Send email from clipboard without opening mail.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041535/send-email-from-clipboard-without-opening-mail-app) and got the code

```
set a to "myemail@mail.com"
tell application "Mail"
    tell (make new outgoing message)
        set subject to (the clipboard)
        set content to "content"
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:a}
        send
    end tell
end tell
```

now I wonder, how could I have a script that do the same thing, but modifies it like this: **if the Subject is the first 10 words, and iff the clipboard har more than 10 words, then the clipboard is cut off.** For example like this "hello there baby this is a long message sent with... [see notes]" and then *the enitre message* (i.e. "hello there baby this is a long message sent with my new email, see you.")  is in the content of the email.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `set subject ...` and `set content ...` lines in your script with the following:

```
if (count of words of (the clipboard)) is greater than 10 then
    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    set subject to ((words 1 through 10 of (the clipboard)) & "... [see notes]") as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    set content to (the clipboard)
else
    set subject to (the clipboard)
    set content to "content"
end if
```

Links to references:

- [`count of` gives the number of elements in a list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/aslr_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW55)
- [`words of` splits a text string into a list, with each element representing a word](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-253199)
- [`AppleScript's text item delimiters` can be manipulated to help split and join lists with different delimiters](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24422)
- [the `through` keyword can be used to get a subrange of items from a list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-BBCHDJJJ)

---

@adayzdone has a good point - sometimes using `words of` to split a string to a list then reassembly with `text item delimiters` can mess up the input data.  You could do this instead:

```
set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
set cblist to text items of (the clipboard)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims

if (count of cblist) is greater than 10 then
    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    set subject to ((items 1 through 10 of cblist) & "... [see notes]") as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    set content to (the clipboard)
else
    set subject to (the clipboard)
    set content to "content"
end if
```

Comment: You don't need to use text item delimiters.

Comment: @adayzdone - Why not?  If I coerce `(words of <xyz>) as text` without setting the delimiter to " ", then the words are concatenated without any spaces in between.

Comment: I read it too quickly. Although I see why you used tid, your script will have problems with a subject such as "Please wire some $$$ to 1-212-555-3333"